# How to use SAS on StorageCredentials for Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I create a SAS on a given table, using the .NET API:

```
        var tablePolicy = new SharedAccessTablePolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(2)),
            Permissions = SharedAccessTablePermissions.Query
        };
        var permissions = new TablePermissions();

        permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("myPolicy", tablePolicy);

        var credentials = new StorageCredentials(
            "#my account here#",
            "#my account secondary key here#");
        var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(
            new Uri("https://#my account here#.table.core.windows.net/"),
            credentials);
        var logTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("WADLogsTable");

        logTable.SetPermissions(permissions);

        var sas = logTable.GetSharedAccessSignature(tablePolicy, "myPolicy", null, null, null, null);
```

I then take this last 'sas' variable and use it to create credentials and perform a query:

```
        var credentials = new StorageCredentials(sas);
        var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(
            new Uri("#my account URI here#"),
            credentials);
        var logTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("WADLogsTable");
        var rows = logTable.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery()).ToArray();
```

I then receive a 403 (forbidden) error.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're getting this error because you're defining both `SharedAccessTablePolicy` and `Policy Name` when creating SAS. So if you use either of the following that should work:

```
var sas = logTable.GetSharedAccessSignature(tablePolicy, null, null, null, null, null);
```

or

```
var sas = logTable.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, "myPolicy", null, null, null, null);
```