# One SAS Token to read from multiple tables

Tags: azure-table-storage

On this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442796/how-to-use-sas-on-storagecredentials-for-azure-table-storage), it is explained how to assign one SAS Token to give read permissions on a single table.
How could I create a SAS Token that can read all tables on my storage? Or provide me a read-only Storage Key.

Answer (score 0):

A single SAS token can only grant permissions to one table, and there is currently no way to obtain a read-only key for the entire account. Consider using a SAS token producer to generate read-only tokens on demand for individual tables. See the following blog post for more information and an example of a SAS token producer:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use an Account SAS Token.

From the Azure docs:

> ## Types of shared access signatures
>
> Version 2015-04-05 of Azure Storage introduces a new type of shared access signature, the account SAS. You can now create either of two types of shared access signatures:
>
> **Account SAS**:
>
> The account SAS delegates access to resources in **one or more of the storage services**. All of the operations available via a service SAS are also available via an account SAS. Additionally, with the account SAS, you can delegate access to operations that apply to a given service, such as Get/Set Service Properties and Get Service Stats. **You can also delegate access to read, write, and delete operations on blob containers, tables, queues, and file shares that are not permitted with a service SAS**. See Constructing an Account SAS for in-depth information about about constructing the account SAS token.
>
> **Service SAS**:
>
> The service SAS delegates access to a resource in just one of the storage services: the Blob, Queue, Table, or File service. See Constructing a Service SAS and Service SAS Examples for in-depth information about constructing the service SAS token.

Source:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

Comment: From the content available at the link above "Note:
Currently, an account SAS must be an ad hoc SAS. Stored access policies are not yet supported for account SAS.".  This means that revocation options are limited and could have wide implications.